# PHP Contact form Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics

I have the following code in my PHP form. How would i adjust it to include my Google Anayltic Code below?:

```
<?php
$sendMail="";
if (isset($_POST["sendemail"])){
$from = $_POST["email"]; 
$subject = $_POST["name"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
$m=mail(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Seller Email', true ),$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
if($m){
    $sendMail="Message sent successfully.";
}else{
    $sendMail="Message not sent.";
}
} ?>

 <!--=== Contact Form ===-->
  <form role="form" class="contactform" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Your email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" data-original-title="" title="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Your name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" data-original-title="" title="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="message">Message</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Information regarding property REF:<?php the_title();?>" style="height:100px;"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" name="sendemail" class="btn btn-lg btn-color">Send</button>
    </div>
    <?php if($sendMail!='') echo '<div class="form-group">'. $sendMail .'</div>';?>
  </form>
</div><div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

My Google Analytics is the following, and I am unsure how I could add this onto the form on submission:

```
    <script>
   (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function() {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
ga('create', 'UA-50671476-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
```

Comment: just insert this piece right after your `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` for example :-) or any other place you choose

Comment: I am looking for the code to track the submission, of the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track `form submission` by creating the Goal in your `Google Analytics` Account.

Goal Type : **Destination Url**

DO one thing, On Successfully Submitted the form take the user to another page and show `"Message Successfully Sent"` there and set the Goal on that page so that you can track the users who successfully submitted the form.

**Code :**

```
<?php
$sendMail="";
if (isset($_POST["sendemail"])){
$from = $_POST["email"]; 
$subject = $_POST["name"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
$m=mail(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Seller Email', true ),$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
if($m){
    header('location:successfull.html');
}else{
    $sendMail="Message not sent.";
}
} ?>

<!--=== Contact Form ===--> 
  <form role="form" class="contactform" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Your email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" data-original-title="" title="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Your name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" data-original-title="" title="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="message">Message</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Information regarding property REF:<?php the_title();?>" style="height:100px;"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" name="sendemail" class="btn btn-lg btn-color">Send</button>
    </div>
    <?php if($sendMail!='') echo '<div class="form-group">'. $sendMail .'</div>';?>
  </form>
</div><div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

**successfull.html** :

## Message Successfully Sent

Steps you have to done in Google Analytics account to setup the Goal :

Admin **->** View **->** Goals **->** New Goal **->** Goal Setup **->** Custom

[image]